# BufferStalledError when i switch the level of the playlist

Tags: hls.js, aws-media-convert

I have 4 streams (1080p60, 1080p30, 720p60, 480p30) in my playlist.m3u8. When i set quality of the video, i switch the level with "nextLevel" and i select the level 0,1,2,3. My problem is that when i switch to 480p30 or 720p60 its woks fine, but when my currentLevel is in 480p30 and I switch to 1080p60 or 720p60 it gives me the "mediaError" => "bufferStalledError". If a switch only the 60fps qualities its works fine.

Someone with the same problem. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Did you manage to fix this? I'm currently having similar issue with hls.js

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your post.  This does not appear to be a MediaConvert issue. It is a player issue, and it appears that your player's buffer management is struggling due to the larger bitrates needed for the higher resolution assets.  Those larger segments will require longer transfer times. You would likely hit the same issue with lesser resolutions if they also used much higher bitrates.

Suggestions: try temporarily setting all renditions to the same bitrate, for example 1500kbps. All the renditions should switch without stalling.  Presuming this works, you have confirmed that a large spread in the bitrates causes the player to have trouble.  The next step from there is to look at adjusting the rendition bitrates and adjusting the pre-fetch amounts and buffering behaviors on your player. I also suggest testing with another player such as bitmovin or wowza to see how the buffering of a higher rendition affects playback on other players.